# What is the syntax to add multiple fonts with Gatsby Plugin Google Fonts?

Tags: syntax, gatsby, google-fonts

This works for the Lobster Two font:

```
  {
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      `Lobster Two`,
      `source sans \pro:400, 400i`, // you can also specify font weights and styles
    ],

    
    display: "swap",
  }
```

I've tried adding Poppins inside of the fonts array and adding a second fonts array but neither have worked. Every video and article so far sees fit to stop at one font as a demonstration.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts` you need to add each specific type like:

```
fonts: [
   `montserrat`, `montserrat\:700`, `montserrat\:900`, `open sans`
  ]
```

This is because the [Google Fonts API has been updated to v2](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2).

I'd recommend using [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2/) instead:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`,
    options: {
      fonts: [
        {
          family: 'Lobster Two',
        },
        {
          family: 'Source Sans Pro',
          weights: ['400, 400i']
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

If the snippet above doesn't work (check the `<link>` generated in the `<header>`) try following the suggested approach in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/pocorschi/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2/issues/5) (transpiling before the format):

```
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`,
    options: {
      fonts: [
       {
         family: 'Lobster Two',
      },
      {
        family: 'Source Sans Pro:ital,wght@1,400;',
      },
     ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! You nailed it. Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure if v2 allows to `display: 'block'` or `display: 'swap'` tho...

Comment: It does according to the docs (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2/)